# Windows Phone 8.1 localStorage issue

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, local-storage, webbrowser-control

I'm interesting if someone have experience loading local html file in windows Phone 8.1 WebBrowser control? It looks like WP treat local files as they don't belong to the same server, so it creates localStorage object for each file separately.

So if you create two WebBrowser controls in your app and load two html files in each of them, they don't see each other data. But if you close app and load it again, each remembered it's own data.

I know that WP 7.1 do not have localStorage, but WP 8.1 do, and I'm wondering why this not work like in Android or iOS.

Do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and it turned out that localStorage is stored separately when navigating via a different protocol. I solved this by referring to HTML source with 'x-wmapp0:' as prefix. This requires you to provide an absolute URI.

```
new System.Uri("x-wmapp0:/www/index.html", UriKind.Absolute);
```